# R logistf - how to define case control penalized logistic regression model with PCA eigenvectors as covariates

Tags: r, regression, logistic, regularization

I wish to carry out logistic regression analysis using Firth's method, as implemented in R logistf package, to analyse SNP case/control data, for rare variants, whilst controlling for stratification using PCA eigenvectors as covariates. I wish to obtain p-values for each SNP (additive model).

Previously I have performed logistic regression analysis using PLINK:

```
plink  --bfile snpdata --logistic --ci 0.95 --covar plink2_pca.eigenvec --covar-number 1-2 --out snpout
```

I would like to perform similar analysis, but wish to handle quasi-complete separation of the rare variants in my data sets.

I have followed a SNP analysis example provided with logistf and been able to obtain P values:

A very small sample of the snpdata (cases: case 1, control 0; SNP additive allele counts for minor allele: 0, 1, 2):

```
           PC01         PC02 case exm226_A exm401_A exm4584_A exm146_A
1  -0.003092320 -0.002737810    1            0       0       0       0
2   0.015637300  0.008232330    1            0       0       0       0
3   0.006746730  0.008704400    1            0       1       0       1
4   0.001438270  0.000875751    0            0       0       0       0
5  -0.004161490  0.011407500    0            0       0       2       0

for(i in 1:ncol(snpdata)) snpdata[,i] <-as.factor(snpdata[,i])
snpdata <- snpdata[sapply(snpdata,function(x) length(levels(x))>=2)] 
fitsnp <- logistf(data=snpdata, formula=case~1, pl=FALSE)
add1(fitsnp)
```

But I am not clear on how to pass the eigenvectors in as covariates, or whether I can used the eigenvector values as is, or need to convert to these as factors?

```
fitsnp <- logistf(data=snpdata,formula=case~(1+PC01+PC02), pl=FALSE)
```

I'm not sure if I am on the right track here and can't find a sufficiently similar example on-line to follow.

I would appreciate any assistance, or explanation if I am going completely wrong here.